# ValueError: Exception encountered when calling layer 'patches_3' Vision Transformer

Tags: transformer-model

These are i have

```
optimizer = tf.keras.optimizers.Adam(learning_rate = learning_rate)

model = vision_transformer()

model.compile(optimizer = optimizer, 
          loss = tf.keras.losses.CategoricalCrossentropy(label_smoothing = 0.1), 
          metrics = ['accuracy'])


STEP_SIZE_TRAIN = train_gen.n // train_gen.batch_size
STEP_SIZE_VALID = val_gen.n // val_gen.batch_size

earlystopping = tf.keras.callbacks.EarlyStopping(monitor = 'val_accuracy',
                                             min_delta = 1e-4,
                                             patience = 5,
                                             mode = 'max',
                                             restore_best_weights = True,
                                             verbose = 1)

checkpointer = tf.keras.callbacks.ModelCheckpoint(filepath = './model.hdf5',
                                              monitor = 'val_accuracy', 
                                              verbose = 1, 
                                              save_best_only = True,
                                              save_weights_only = True,
                                              mode = 'max')

callbacks = [earlystopping, lr_scheduler, checkpointer]

model.fit(x = train_gen,
      steps_per_epoch = STEP_SIZE_TRAIN,
      validation_data = val_gen,
      validation_steps = STEP_SIZE_VALID,
      epochs = num_epochs,
      callbacks = callbacks)
```

with
Train_Gen Found 817 validated image filenames belonging to 2 classes
and Val_gen Found 205 validated image filenames belonging to 2 classes.

I got error ;

```
ValueError                                Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-45-ad98692117eb> in <cell line: 29>()
     27 callbacks = [earlystopping, lr_scheduler, checkpointer]
     28 
---> 29 model.fit(x = train_gen,
     30           steps_per_epoch = STEP_SIZE_TRAIN,
     31           validation_data = val_gen,
```

[Error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Ggfk8.jpg)